# Response Character Encoding

Tags: ktor

How can I explicitly set the character encoding (e.g. UTF-8) in a response?

```
call.respondText("Hello World!", ContentType.Text.Plain, HttpStatusCode.OK)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call the [withCharset](https://api.ktor.io/ktor-http/io.ktor.http/with-charset.html) method on a `ContentType` object to create a copy with specified charset:

```
call.respondText("Hello World!", ContentType.Text.Plain.withCharset(Charsets.UTF_8), HttpStatusCode.OK)
```

Comment: Is working. Just made test with Charsets.US_ASCII. Thanks!